# The background is clipped when scrolling

Tags: reactjs, scroll, jsx, use-effect, use-ref

In my React app I have a problem on small-height screens: when I scroll the sidebar menu the background (background-color) is clipped and does not stretch to full scroll height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the height is set as 100vh.

at big screens is works perfect. But at small screens we don't now the real scroll height - it depends on browser window resolution

we need to use useRef Hook and watch the element's scroll height change

```
const appMenuRef = useRef(null)
const [fullHeight, setFullHeight] = useState('100vh')

useEffect(() => { 
    if (!isNull(appMenuRef.current)) {
      setFullHeight(`calc(${appMenuRef.current.scrollHeight - appMenuRef.current.scrollTop}px)`)
    }
  }, [appMenuRef])
```

now we can set this fullHeight as css inline property to problematic element